# Phonegap plugin for ios...javascript part

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, plugins, cordova

I need to create a phonegap plugin for ios which fetches all artists from the music library. I know how to do this in Objective C but I have no idea about javascript. I read the phongegap plugin docs for iOS but I dont understand the javascript parts. Please help.
Heres my code...

```
Artist.m

#import "Artist.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <PhoneGap/PGPlugin.h>
@implementation Artist

-(void)getArtistNames:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options
{
    MPMediaQuery *query=[MPMediaQuery artistsQuery];
    NSArray *artists=[query collections];
    artistNames=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(MPMediaItemCollection *collection in artists)
    {
        MPMediaItem *item=[collection representativeItem];
        [artistNames addObject:[[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
    }
    uniqueNames=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for(id object in artistNames)
    {
        if(![uniqueNames containsObject:object])
        {
            [uniqueNames addObject:object];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",uniqueNames);

    PluginResult *pluginResult=[PluginResult resultWithStatus:PGCommandStatus_OK messageAsArray:uniqueNames];
    [self writeJavascript:[pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:[arguments pop]]];

}

@end
```

> **Artist.js**

```
var ArtistPlugin={};

ArtistPlugin.prototype.getArtistNames = function(types, success, fail)
{

          return PhoneGap.exec(success, fail, "Artist", "getArtistNames", types);
}
```

in index.html...

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="Artist.js"></script>

function onDeviceReady()
    {
        // do your thing!

        navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working");
        alert('asdasd');
        var abc=Artist.getArtistNames(types, success, fail);

        alert(abc);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things:

1. It's best to keep the names the same between your main class in Obj-C and JavaScript. In your case that would mean that either your Obj-C class should be called `ArtistPlugin` or the JavaScript object you create (and it's filename) should be called `Artist`. I would go with all being called `ArtistPlugin`. Less likely to clash.
2. The final argument to `PhoneGap.exec` is an Array, so unless `types` is an array, it should probably look like: `return PhoneGap.exec(success, fail, "Artist", "getArtistNames", [types]);`
3. Lastly, make sure you have an entry in the plugins section of your PhoneGap.plist file. The key and value would be the homogenous name you chose from step #1 (i.e.: key: ArtistPlugin, value: ArtistPlugin).

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes i got it to work now, still i prefer objective C anyday :)